# Catching integrity error in django generic view for ajax forms

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

In django CreateView i have two fields which should be unique together.

ie. say user and unique_name

To catch the Integrity Error (when a user has a duplicate unique_name), I have written try and except in normal Django Function. And it works great with HTML form submission.
However when I am trying to use Ajax to submit the form, I can find no way to catch the error.

`class DataCreate(AjaxableResponseMixin,CreateView):
    model = Prescriptions
    fields = ['user','unique_name','x','y','z']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('some url')`

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    try:
        return super(DataCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    except IntegrityError:
        form.add_error('unique_name','You already have a user by that name')
        return render_to_response('html')

def save(self):
    request.session['unique_name'] = self.object.unique_name
    super(DataCreate,self).save() </code>
```

Note : Ajax Mixin is taken from Django Documentation(1.7) as follows.
 
`class AjaxableResponseMixin(object):
    """
    Mixin to add AJAX support to a form.
    Must be used with an object-based FormView (e.g. CreateView)
    """
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return response`

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # We make sure to call the parent's form_valid() method because
    # it might do some processing (in the case of CreateView, it will
    # call form.save() for example).
    response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_valid(form)
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        data = {
            'pk': self.object.pk,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `form_invalid` in the except clause rather than using `render_to_response`

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    try:
        return super(DataCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    except IntegrityError:
        form.add_error('unique_name','You already have a user by that name')
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Shouldn't we be using `except IntegrityError as e:`?

Comment: Only if you need access to the instance of the exception.